# Why doesn't HtmlUnitDriver execute JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, selenium, htmlunit-driver

I got the following problem:
I am running a JUnit testCase with Selenium 2.9 using HtmlUnitDriver with Browserversion Firefox_3_6. JavaScript is enabled. Now when it should call and execute the following javaScript function it does nothing:

```
function openIdsDocument()
{
    var windowBounds = getWindowBounds();
    var XMLHTTP = getAjaxRequestObject("XYZ.do?availableWidth="+windowBounds.width+"&availableHeight="+windowBounds.height, "", true);
    if (XMLHTTP != null)
    {
            XMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = function alertAJAXResponse()
            {
                    if (XMLHTTP.readyState == 4)
                    {
                            window.location.href = getContextPath() + "ABC.do";
                    }
            };
            XMLHTTP.send("timestamp=" + <%=System.currentTimeMillis()%>);
    }
    getLoadingState();
}
```

I want to get to ABC.do

If I execute my test with the FirefoxDriver it works.

Is there a way to get this working with HtmlUnitDriver?
My test works if I manually call driver.get("http://host/ABC.do") but that cannot be the right way to do this.

Comment: Did you add some timespan to wait after the the page is requested that contains this java script. HtmlUnitDriver seams need more explicite waits then FireFoxDriver?

Comment: I set the driver to implicitly wait for 10 seconds: 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); already tried other methods of waiting, effect is the same

Answer (score 21):

You can enable JavaScript by doing either

- `new HtmlUnitDriver(true);`
- `driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);`

What you need to do is to wait until the JavaScript is executed after `get(url)`.

You can use `Thread.sleep()` method for adding some delay.

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get(url);

Thread.sleep(100);

runTest();
```

**Update**

As @Corey indicated in the comments, it could be nicer to use [Explicit and Implicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) instead of `Thread.sleep()`. As I don't use them these days, I cannot confirm, though. It would be great if someone test them and update this answer.

Comment: don't use static sleeps

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Care to explain why?

Comment: it's generally an anti-pattern in tests

Comment: Yeah, I can guess the reason, but I think it's better to use it than giving up on writing a test because it's generally an anti-pattern. Of course, it would be nice if there was an alternative.

Comment: there *is* an alternative

Comment: Great. What is it? I'm not being offensive. I really want to know.

Comment: usually explicit and implicit waits http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: Nice updated the answer. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 6):

You need to initialize the [`HtmlUnitDriver` with enable javascript `true`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver/2.0a1/selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.0a1-javadoc.jar!/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html#HtmlUnitDriver%28boolean%29)

```
new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

Comment: Hi Ralph I have JavaScript enabled with the following code:   
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Tarken: I don't know - test it!

Comment: If I do it that way I am no longer emulating Firefox. Since I have to change  driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.Firefox_3_6) to driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true). If I do that I cannot pass the browsercompatibility check anymore.

Comment: For me, new HtmlUnitDriver(true) and setJavascriptEnabled(true) does NOT give same results. First one ignores JS errors, second one throws an exception.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to set the `BrowserVersion` as well as enable Javascript with HtmlUnitDriver, your initialization needs to look like the following (as there is no way to do both via the constructor):

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

This will allow you to use the browser definition of your choice and use Javascript.

Comment: That is what I was doing from the beginning and that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to do this:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8);
((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, There is an easy way to enable browser capability and javascript, you can do the following:

```
Webdriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.Chrome,true);
```

True specifies that javascript should be enabled. @Glenn Nelson,