# HtmlUnitDriver does not load javascript when navigating a page from an url

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

Here is my problem, I'm trying to load my website page for testing it but when i look at the html I get from the HtmlUnitDriver, elements displayed with javascript are not present.
I am using selenium-java 3.141.59 and htmlunit-driver 2.33.3
Here is my code

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926246/why-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript");
driver.getPageSource();
```

I tried it on a stack overflow page, and in the DOM get from the driver there is a tag saying that "javascript is not enabled"

```
   <noscript>

    &lt;div id="noscript-warning"&gt;Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled
        &lt;img src="https://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;

   </noscript>
```

I tried different Browsers and ways to enable javascript but nothing happened

Comment: If you open the page with a browser and have a look at the page code, there are several noscript tags inside the page. The existence of the tag has nothing to do with the availability of javascript. The browser will render the tag only if javascript is not available....

Answer (score 0):

### HTML `<noscript>` Tag

The [`<noscript>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) tag defines an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn't support script. The `<noscript>` element can be used in both `<head>` and `<body>`. When used inside the `<head>` element, `<noscript>` must contain only `<link>`, `<style>`, or `<meta>` elements. The content inside the `<noscript>` element will be displayed if scripts are not supported, or are disabled in the user's browser. 
When I tried your code block:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926246/why-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

I got an error at the line:

```
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

As:

```
The method setJavascriptEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type WebDriver
```

There are two solutions:

- Either **cast** the driver instance and invoke `setJavascriptEnabled(true)` as follows:

  ```
  ((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
  ```
- Or pass the argument **true** which enables **javascript** support as follows:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926246/why-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript");
  System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
  driver.quit();
  ```
- In both the cases the output is identical as follows:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage" class="html__responsive">
    <head>
      <title>
        java - Why doesn't HtmlUnitDriver execute JavaScript? - Stack Overflow
      </title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d"/>
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"/>
      <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
      <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
      <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926246/why-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript"/>
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow"/>
      <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded"/>
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
      <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
      <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Why doesn't HtmlUnitDriver execute JavaScript?"/>
      <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="I got the following problem:
  I am running a JUnit testCase with Selenium 2.9 using HtmlUnitDriver with Browserversion Firefox_3_6. JavaScript is enabled. Now when it should call and execute the fol..."/>
      <script src="https://rules.quantcount.com/rules-p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.js" async="">
      </script>
      <script async="" src="https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js">
      </script>
      <script async="" src="https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js">
      </script>
      <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
      </script>
      <script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js">
      </script>
      <script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/rtv/011811091519050/amp4ads-host-v0.js">
      </script>
      <script src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_rendering_278.js?21062890">
      </script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=86fc07b77cb3">
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=5023e4724ed5"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary-unified.css?v=9424d9dcf4a3"/>
      <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question 'Why doesn't HtmlUnitDriver execute JavaScript?'" href="/feeds/question/7926246"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="Stack Exchange iOS"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="871299723"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926246/why-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="Stack Exchange iOS"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="871299723"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926246/why-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="Stack Exchange Android"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926246/why-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript"/>
      <meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="com.stackexchange.marvin"/>
      <script>
  //<![CDATA[


          StackExchange.ready(function () {

              StackExchange.using("snippets", function () {
              StackExchange.snippets.initSnippetRenderer();
              });


          StackExchange.using("postValidation", function () {
              StackExchange.postValidation.initOnBlurAndSubmit($('#post-form'), 2, 'answer');
          });


          StackExchange.question.init({showAnswerHelp:true,totalCommentCount:2,shownCommentCount:2,highlightColor:'#F4A83D',backgroundColor:'#FFF',questionId:7926246});

          styleCode();

              StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToQuestion('1', '7926246');
                              StackExchange.using("gps", function () { StackExchange.gps.trackOutboundClicks('#content', '.post-text'); });

          });

  //]]>
      </script>
      <script>
  //<![CDATA[

          StackExchange.ready(function () {
              var d = 100;
              $.ajax({url:"https://cdn.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/wb4qa.js?v=5",cache:true,dataType:"script"}).done(function tryInit() {
              if (window.WinterBash) {
                  WinterBash.core.init('winterbash2018.stackexchange.com', 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/WinterBash/', '3', false);
              } else {
                  if (d <= 800)
                  setTimeout(tryInit, d);
                  d *= 2;
              }
              });
          });

  //]]>
      </script>
      <script>
  //<![CDATA[

      StackExchange.init({"locale":"en","serverTime":1544623167,"routeName":"Questions/Show","stackAuthUrl":"https://stackauth.com","networkMetaHostname":"meta.stackexchange.com","site":{"name":"Stack Overflow","description":"Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers","isNoticesTabEnabled":true,"enableNewTagCreationWarning":true,"insertSpaceAfterNameTabCompletion":false,"id":1,"childUrl":"https://meta.stackoverflow.com","enableSocialMediaInSharePopup":true,"protocol":"https"},"user":{"fkey":"29da02f0855a8cc9776a70151ea3e3d68966e60e54f9aa3b2491a5234ecba3cc","tid":"608f762a-97db-360f-08db-c52d8278395c","rep":0,"isAnonymous":true,"isAnonymousNetworkWide":true,"ab":{"inline_signup_hero":{"v":"d","g":1}}},"events":{"postType":{"question":1},"postEditionSection":{"title":1,"body":2,"tags":3}},"story":{"minCompleteBodyLength":75,"likedTagsMaxLength":300,"dislikedTagsMaxLength":300},"jobPreferences":{"maxNumDeveloperRoles":2,"maxNumIndustries":4},"svgIconPath":"https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/svg-icons","svgIconHash":"38192da1e2db"}, {"site":{"allowImageUploads":true,"enableUserHovercards":true,"styleCode":true,"enableImgurHttps":true,"forceHttpsImages":true,"stacksValidation":true},"userMessaging":{},"comments":{},"userProfile":{"openGraphAPIKey":"58740831ad23540e00c58987"},"tags":{},"accounts":{"currentPasswordRequiredForChangingStackIdPassword":true},"flags":{"allowRetractingFlags":true},"snippets":{"snippetsEnabled":true,"renderDomain":"stacksnippets.net"},"paths":{},"markdown":{"asteriskIntraWordEmphasis":true},"monitoring":{"clientTimingsAbsoluteTimeout":30000,"clientTimingsDebounceTimeout":1000},"mentions":{"maxNumUsersInDropdown":50},"slack":{"sidebarAdDismissCookie":"slack-sidebar-ad"}});
      StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({"js/prettify-full.en.js":"537577215963","js/moderator.en.js":"c48addfbc3c8","js/full-anon.en.js":"4dc78e89befa","js/full.en.js":"7b0d3adc4723","js/wmd.en.js":"942921cd6aa6","js/mobile.en.js":"0530e6d963ab","js/help.en.js":"ea9b6d3ca995","js/tageditor.en.js":"f5ffd857ba9d","js/tageditornew.en.js":"dbec77975b56","js/inline-tag-editing.en.js":"97b4a0d9f86f","js/revisions.en.js":"8f22ba768cac","js/review.en.js":"94323c3bdabd","js/tagsuggestions.en.js":"b278f9a0b23b","js/post-validation.en.js":"70b289599a70","js/explore-qlist.en.js":"222b04ca33bc","js/events.en.js":"dd2d0d0578a0","js/keyboard-shortcuts.en.js":"390ab347f2c4","js/external-editor.en.js":"cca27370f403","js/adops.en.js":"22a9bd59b1e9","js/begin-edit-event.en.js":"7415f5dee62d","js/external-editor.en.js":"cca27370f403","js/snippet-javascript.en.js":"ebc751779f44","js/snippet-javascript-codemirror.en.js":"fa05a6e17d62"});
      StackExchange.using("gps", function() {
           StackExchange.gps.init(true);
      });

  //]]>
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/styles/clc.min.css?v=1db48f495ba1" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.co.in/adsid/integrator.js?domain=stackoverflow.com"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.co.in/adsid/integrator.js?domain=stackoverflow.com">
      </script>
      <link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=stackoverflow.com"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=stackoverflow.com">
      </script>
      <script src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_278.js?21062890" async="">
      </script>
      <link rel="prefetch" href="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-31/html/container.html"/>
      <script async="" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js?v=4dc78e89befa">
      </script>
      <script async="" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=ebc751779f44">
      </script>
      <script async="" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/post-validation.en.js?v=70b289599a70">
      </script>
      <script async="" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.en.js?v=537577215963">
      </script>
      <script async="" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/external-editor.en.js?v=cca27370f403">
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/WinterBash/css/wb4qa.css?v=2"/>
    </head>
    <body class="question-page unified-theme">
      <noscript id="noscript-css">
        &lt;style&gt;body,.top-bar{margin-top:1.9em}&lt;/style&gt;
      </noscript>
      <div id="notify-container">
      </div>
      <div id="custom-header">
      </div>
      <header class="top-bar js-top-bar top-bar__network _fixed">
        <div class="-container">
      <div class="-main">
        <a href="#" class="left-sidebar-toggle p0 ai-center jc-center js-left-sidebar-toggle">
          <span class="ps-relative">
          </span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="-logo js-gps-track" data-gps-track="top_nav.click({is_current:false, location:2, destination:8})">
          <span class="-img _glyph">
            Stack Overflow
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <form id="search" action="/search" method="get" class="searchbar js-searchbar " autocomplete="off" role="search">
        <div class="ps-relative">
          <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search…" value="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="240" class="f-input js-search-field "/>
          <button type="submit" aria-label="Search..." class="s-btn s-btn__primary btn-topbar-primary js-search-submit">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconSearch" width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18">
          <path d="M12.86 11.32L18 16.5 16.5 18l-5.18-5.14v-.35a7 7 0 1 1 1.19-1.19h.35zM7 12A5 5 0 1 0 7 2a5 5 0 0 0 0 10z"/>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ol class="-secondary js-secondary-topbar-links drop-icons-responsively the-js-is-handling-responsiveness">
        <li class="-item searchbar-trigger js-searchbar-trigger">
          <a href="#" class="-link">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconSearch" width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18">
          <path d="M12.86 11.32L18 16.5 16.5 18l-5.18-5.14v-.35a7 7 0 1 1 1.19-1.19h.35zM7 12A5 5 0 1 0 7 2a5 5 0 0 0 0 10z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="-item">
          <a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/?tab=inbox" class="-link js-inbox-button" title="Recent inbox messages">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconInbox" width="20" height="18" viewbox="0 0 20 18">
          <path d="M15.19 1H4.63c-.85 0-1.6.54-1.85 1.35L0 10.79V15c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-4.21l-2.87-8.44A2 2 0 0 0 15.19 1zm-.28 10l-2 2h-6l-2-2H1.96L4.4 3.68A1 1 0 0 1 5.35 3h9.12a1 1 0 0 1 .95.68L17.86 11h-2.95z"/>
            </svg>
            <span class="indicator-badge js-unread-count _important" style="display: none;">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="-item">
          <a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/?tab=reputation" class="-link js-achievements-button" title="Recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned" data-unread-class="_highlighted-positive">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconAchievements" width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18">
          <path d="M15 2V1H3v1H0v4c0 1.6 1.4 3 3 3v1c.4 1.5 3 2.6 5 3v2H5s-1 1.5-1 2h10c0-.4-1-2-1-2h-3v-2c2-.4 4.6-1.5 5-3V9c1.6-.2 3-1.4 3-3V2h-3zM3 7c-.5 0-1-.5-1-1V4h1v3zm8.4 2.5L9 8 6.6 9.4l1-2.7L5 5h3l1-2.7L10 5h2.8l-2.3 1.8 1 2.7h-.1zM16 6c0 .5-.5 1-1 1V4h1v2z"/>
            </svg>
            <span class="indicator-badge js-unread-count _positive" style="display: none;">
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="-item help-button-item" data-remove-order="1">
          <a href="#" class="-link js-help-button" title="Help Center and other resources">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconHelp" width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18">
          <path d="M9 1a8 8 0 1 0 0 16A8 8 0 0 0 9 1zm.81 12.13c-.02.71-.55 1.15-1.24 1.13-.66-.02-1.17-.49-1.15-1.2.02-.72.56-1.18 1.22-1.16.7.03 1.2.51 1.17 1.23zM11.77 8a5.8 5.8 0 0 1-1.02.91l-.53.37c-.26.2-.42.43-.5.69a4 4 0 0 0-.09.75c0 .05-.03.16-.18.16H7.88c-.16 0-.18-.1-.18-.15.03-.66.12-1.21.4-1.66a5.29 5.29 0 0 1 1.43-1.22c.16-.12.28-.25.38-.39a1.34 1.34 0 0 0 .02-1.71c-.24-.31-.51-.46-1.03-.46-.51 0-.8.26-1.02.6-.21.33-.18.73-.18 1.1H5.75c0-1.38.35-2.25 1.1-2.76.52-.35 1.17-.5 1.93-.5 1 0 1.79.18 2.49.71.64.5.98 1.18.98 2.12 0 .57-.2 1.05-.48 1.44z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="-item site-switcher-item">
          <a href="https://stackexchange.com" class="-link js-site-switcher-button js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.show" title="A list of all 174 Stack Exchange sites">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconStackExchange" width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18">
          <path d="M1 13c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8v3l3-3h1a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-2H1v2zM15 1H3a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v2h16V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zM1 6h16v4H1V6z"/>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="-ctas">
          <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&amp;returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f7926246%2fwhy-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript" class="login-link s-btn btn-topbar-clear py8" rel="nofollow">
            Log In
          </a>
          <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&amp;returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent" class="login-link s-btn s-btn__primary py8 btn-topbar-primary" rel="nofollow" data-ga="[&quot;sign up&quot;,&quot;Sign Up Navigation&quot;,&quot;Header&quot;,null,null]">
            Sign Up
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="-dialog-container js-topbar-dialog-corral">
          <div class="topbar-dialog siteSwitcher-dialog dno">
            <div class="header">
          <h3>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
              current community
            </a>
          </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content current-site-container">
          <ul class="current-site">
            <li class="grid">
              <div class="fl1">
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="current-site-link site-link js-gps-track grid gs8 gsx" data-id="1" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:3 })">
              <div class="favicon favicon-stackoverflow site-icon grid--cell" title="Stack Overflow">
              </div>
              <span class="grid--cell fl1">

          Stack Overflow

              </span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="related-links">
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/help" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:14 })">
              help
                </a>
                <a href="https://chat.stackoverflow.com" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:6 })">
              chat
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="related-site grid">
              <div class="L-shaped-icon-container">
                <span class="L-shaped-icon">
                </span>
              </div>
              <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com" class="site-link js-gps-track grid gs8 gsx" data-id="552" data-gps-track="site.switch({ target_site:552, item_type:3 }),site_switcher.click({ item_type:4 })">
                <div class="favicon favicon-stackoverflowmeta site-icon grid--cell" title="Meta Stack Overflow">
                </div>
                <span class="grid--cell fl1">

          Meta Stack Overflow

                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="header" id="your-communities-header">
          <h3>

  your communities            
          </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content" id="your-communities-section">
          <div class="call-to-login">
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent" class="login-link js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:10 })">
              Sign up
            </a>
             or 
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f7926246%2fwhy-doesnt-htmlunitdriver-execute-javascript" class="login-link js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site_switcher.click({ item_type:11 })">
              log in
            </a>
             to customize your list.

          </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header">
          <h3>
            <a href="https://stackexchange.com/sites">
              more stack exchange communities
            </a>
          </h3>
          <a href="https://stackoverflow.blog" class="fr">
            company blog
          </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="child-content">
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="topbar-dialog help-dialog js-help-dialog dno">
            <div class="modal-content">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="/tour" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="help_popup.click({ item_type:1 })">

  .
  .
  .

      getLoadingState
                </span>
                <span class="pun">
                  ();
                </span>
                <span class="pln">
                </span>
                <span class="pun">
                  }
                </span>
              </code>
                </pre>
                <p>
              I want to get to ABC.do 
                </p>
                <p>
              If I execute my test with the FirefoxDriver it works.
                </p>
                <p>
              Is there a way to get this working with HtmlUnitDriver?
  My test works if I manually call driver.get("
              <a href="http://host/ABC.do" rel="noreferrer">
                http://host/ABC.do
              </a>
              ") but that cannot be the right way to do this.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="post-taglist grid gs4 gsy fd-column">
                <div class="grid ps-relative d-block">
              <a href="/questions/tagged/java" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'java'" rel="tag">
                java
              </a>
              <a href="/questions/tagged/javascript" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'javascript'" rel="tag">
                javascript
              </a>
              <a href="/questions/tagged/ajax" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'ajax'" rel="tag">
                ajax
              </a>
              <a href="/questions/tagged/selenium" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'selenium'" rel="tag">
                selenium
              </a>
              <a href="/questions/tagged/htmlunit-driver" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'htmlunit-driver'" rel="tag">
                htmlunit-driver
              </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb0 ">
                <div class="mt16 pt4 grid gs8 gsy fw-wrap jc-end ai-start">
              <div class="grid--cell mr16" style="flex: 1 1 100px;">
                <div class="post-menu">
                  <a href="/q/7926246" title="short permalink to this question" class="short-link" id="link-post-7926246">
                    share
                  </a>
                  <span class="lsep">
                    |
                  </span>
                  <a href="/posts/7926246/edit" class="suggest-edit-post" title="">
                    improve this question
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="post-signature grid--cell">
                <div class="user-info user-hover">
                  <div class="user-action-time">
                    <a href="/posts/7926246/revisions" title="show all edits to this post">
                  edited 
                  <span title="2016-03-31 13:31:33Z" class="relativetime">
                    Mar 31 '16 at 13:31
                  </span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-gravatar32">
                    <a href="/users/759866/benjamin">
                  <div class="gravatar-wrapper-32">
                    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cc21bd143a63dbea51c2caa5f1e8599b?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" width="32" height="32"/>
                  </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="user-details">
                    <a href="/users/759866/benjamin">
                  Benjamin
                    </a>
                    <div class="-flair">
                  <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score 15,789" dir="ltr">
                    15.8k
                  </span>
                  <span title="28 gold badges">
                    <span class="badge1">
                    </span>
                    <span class="badgecount">
                      28
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <span title="119 silver badges">
                    <span class="badge2">
                    </span>
                    <span class="badgecount">
                      119
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <span title="230 bronze badges">
                    <span class="badge3">
                    </span>
                    <span class="badgecount">
                      230
                    </span>
                  </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="post-signature owner grid--cell">
                <div class="user-info ">
                  <div class="user-action-time">
  .
  .
  .
      </script>
      <noscript>

      &lt;div id="noscript-warning"&gt;Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled
          &lt;img src="https://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno"&gt;
      &lt;/div&gt;

      </noscript>
      <script>
  //<![CDATA[

          (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
          i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function() { (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments) }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
          m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
          })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

          StackExchange.ready(function () {

          StackExchange.ga.init({
              sendTitles: true,
              tracker: window.ga,
              trackingCodes: [
              'UA-108242619-1'
              ]
          });



              StackExchange.ga.setDimension('dimension2', '|java|javascript|ajax|selenium|htmlunit-driver|');

              StackExchange.ga.setDimension('dimension3', 'Questions/Show');


          StackExchange.ga.trackPageView();
          });

  /**/

          var _qevents = _qevents || [],
          _comscore = _comscore || [];
          (function() {
          var ssl = 'https:' == document.location.protocol,
              s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
              qc = document.createElement('script');
           qc.async = true;
              qc.src = (ssl ? 'https://secure' : 'http://edge') + '.quantserve.com/quant.js';
              s.parentNode.insertBefore(qc, s);
              _qevents.push({ qacct: "p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc" });
  /**/
           var sc = document.createElement('script');
              sc.async = true;
              sc.src = (ssl ? 'https://sb' : 'http://b') + '.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js';
              s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, s);
              _comscore.push({ c1: "2", c2: "17440561" });
          })();



  //]]>
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```