# Unknown Host in selenium HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, htmlunit-driver

I am getting Unknown Host as a return of driver.getPageSource()

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://s2fs.filedump.com");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
}
```

I am getting output as Unknown host. 
Url which is used in `driver.get` is accessible only in my company network.
Moreover when I'm using **chrome driver** to access same url it is working fine as it returning page source html.

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724856/htmlunitdriver-does-not-load-javascript-when-navigating-a-page-from-an-url/53744963#53744963) helps you?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnitDriver is a part of Selenium and instead of HtmlUnitDriver driver you have to use  WebDriver driver.

please refer below code :

```
 WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
 driver.get("https://www.google.com");
 System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
 driver.quit();
```

Comment: not working.. I am getting same output as "Unknown host"

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is the problem of proxy, I use the following code

```
 WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

 Proxy proxy=new Proxy();
 proxy.setHttpProxy("mycompanyproxy.xyz:port");
 ((HtmlUnitDriver)driver).setProxySettings(proxy);

 driver.get("https://www.google.com");
 System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
 driver.quit();
```